# devise redirect to a custom url when not confirmed instead of flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Implemented with a custom failure class for devise what is the trigger to detect if a user is non confirmed? warden_message does not work. Anyone knows?

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def redirect_url

    if warden_options[:scope] == :user
      new_user_registration_path
    else
      new_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def respond

    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      store_location!
      flash[:alert] = i18n_message unless flash[:notice]

      if warden_message == :unconfirmed
        redirect_to "/confirm"
      else
        redirect_to sign_in_path
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: so? what is the problem? do you get an error or what?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223555/devise-with-confirmable-redirect-user-to-a-custom-page-when-users-tries-to-sig

Comment: @phoet it does not redirect anymore, the confirm path is never routed to

Comment: and what did you do to debug it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to redirect users to a custom URL, you should do it in `redirect_url`, not in `respond`:

```
def redirect_url
  if warden_message == :unconfirmed
    '/confirm'
  else
    new_user_registration_path
  end
end
```